# Изменяются имена аргументов методов интерфейса

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven

В одном проекте создан интерфейc ICar, в нем есть методы

```
CarsReturnCode addOwner(Owner owner);
CarsReturnCode addCar(Car car);
CarsReturnCode addModel(Model model);
CarsReturnCode updateOwner(int regNumber, int ownerId);
CarsReturnCode removeOwner(int ownerId);
```

и т.д.

В другом проекте с помощью Maven создаю dependency. Создаю класс, имплементирующий интерфейс ICar. Как только я имплементирую методы то в некоторых методах имена аргументов изменяются и выглядят так:

```
CarsReturnCode updateOwner(int i, int i1){
    return null;
}
CarsReturnCode removeOwner(int i){
    return null;
}
```

Почему меняются имена аргументов? Как это можно решить?

Comment: В `idea` можно выставить автозагрузку артефактов сырцов и документации. В твоём же случае надо ещё и сделать их. Тогда переменные будут называться красиво.

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы знать какие имена использовать, IDEA нужен из проекта, в котором наследуется интерфейс, доступ к исходному коду проекта, в котором этот интерфейс определён. Зайдите в Project Structure → Modules → Dependencies и укажите один проект зависимостью другого.

Comment: Разве не для этого используют Maven? Сейчас я так и делаю - работает, но у меня цель сделать это через мавен. =/

Comment: @Zamet85 maven подтягивает скомпилированный jar-файл, где нет названия переменных.

Comment: Т.е. выход только один, как и сказал @sergey?

Comment: Есть ещё два - использовать автосгенерированные имена параметров или исправить их вручную.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, я извиняюсь за глупые вопросы - только учусь. А как тогда получается что через тот же maven используются библиотеки Spring и т.д. и там переменные выглядят нормально? Видимо где то они описываются дополнительно?

Comment: @SergeyNikulin это не глупый вопрос, наоборот даже интересный. Я на него ответа не знаю. Может быть, IDEA использует параметр scm/connection для доступа к исходному коду Spring.